# Linear algebra proof - invertible matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> I need to set up a proof for this problem:
>
> Given that $A$ and $B$ are both $n\times n$ matrices.  $A$ is
>    invertible, and $AB=BA$.
>
> Prove that $A^{-1}B=BA^{-1}$.

I'm just unsure how to go about this particular proof.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: Multiply both sides by $A^{-1}$ on the left, then on right:

> $$A^{-1} AB A^{-1} = A^{-1} BA A^{-1} \\ BA^{-1} = A^{-1}B$$

Answer (score 3):

You could try to start with the fact that $AB=BA$ and multiply one side by $A^{-1}$.
After that, do the same with the other side. You should find what you wanted to prove.

Question for you: what does $AA^{-1}$ equals?

Answer (score 0):

Since A is invertible we have that $AA^{-1}=I$.

We are told$$ AB = BA$$ Then if you multiply both sides by $A^{-1}$we have:

$$A^{-1}AB = A^{-1}BA$$ $$IB = A^{-1}BA B=A^{-1}BA, BA^{-1}=A^{-1}BAA^{-1}, BA^{-1}=A^{-1}B(AA^{-1}),BA^{-1}=A^{-1}BI$$ $$BA^{-1}=A^{-1}B$$